# Clarifications on using ていく with verbs - using 着る as example verb

Tags: grammar, verbs, て-form

I'm finding the application of ていく (and by extension てくる) difficult to understand, so I want to use an example with the verb 着る to ask some questions on it:

1. If someone wore their jacket and left me (getting further and further away from me), does it make sense to use the ていく verb to express the gradual physical increase in distance between us after the jacket is worn?
2. If I continue to wear my old jacket because buying the new one is expensive, and I want to use 着る + ていく to add the nuance of saying I'll continue to wear it (time-related movement), which of the below is the right way to convey this meaning? Not too sure on whether the いく needs to be conjugated to ている form to keep the meaning of the ongoing action, because 着る just becomes conjunctive.

> この古い上着着ていく。

> この古い上着着ていって(い)る。

3. And if I stopped wearing by old jacket because I bought a new one, which of these are valid ways of saying I stopped wearing the old one?

> この古い上着着ていかない。

> この古い上着着なくていく。

> この古い上着着ていって(い)ない。

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: In any event there should be a particle of some sort between 上着 and the verb, except perhaps in a casual spoken context.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are all no. 着ていく just means to put it on and go, to go wearing it or to put on clothes one after another whether you change it every time or put on another over the current one.

Comment: Is your answer specific to the verb 着る? I think I understand the answer is no for the first question, but the grammar resources I'm referencing describes Verb +ていく as something that can be applicable to habitual actions, something you do or don't do from now on. Would your answer for the second and third questions differ based on the verb?